# Generating Comment Header in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Is there a snippet or add-on to generate the comment header for methods and classes in Visual Studio 2008.

Currently i just type /// to generate the header. Is there an add-on to run a code through and add the comment header for methods, members and classes that doesn't have one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/GhostDoc) add-in. AFAIK it can't automatically run through the code and add comments, but it will save you a lot of typing

Answer (score 2):

I second @aku for GhostDoc.  I use it every single day on the purchased code-base that I maintain and extend.  I've bound ctrl-shift-d, d to generate documentation and ctrl-shift-d, r to regenerate documentation.

Wonderful, just wonderful.

Don't expect the generated documentation to be extraordinarily accurate and helpful, however.  For

```
public string DocumentGenerate(int generationParameter)
```

It will generate something like

```
/// <summary>
/// Generates the Document
/// </summary
/// <param "generationParameter">The generation Parameter</param>
/// <returns></returns>
```

Which, while accurate, could be more helpful.  You'll need to flesh out the documentation.